# I'm having trouble in using Position Tag in css

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want a container in which there is a block rectangle, and inside that block I want 2 rectangles, 1 positioned at top and other at bottom, and then I want a circle in side that box. the first containers position must be fixed and others must not affect spaces with each other. I want all elements to have a fixed position so that I can enter text anywhere I want without any changes being made. I also want to apply a php for each loop on li, so these elements must be scrollable. Thank You.

```css
.image{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaaaaa;
    width: 480px;
    height: 640px;
    padding: 0.5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.top_bar{
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaaaaa;
    width: 478px;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 1px;
}

.middle_bar{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 478px;
    height: 534px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-top: 38px;
}

.bottom_bar{
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaaaaa;
    width: 478px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1000px;

} 
.dot {
    background-color: #f50057;
    position: absolute;

    background-color: solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #aaaaaa;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.text_center_white {
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    } 

.text_center_black {
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>DS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image">     
            <div class="top_bar"> <div class="text_center_white">Text</div>
                <div class="bottom_bar">
                    <div class='middle_bar'> <div class="text_center_black" ><p>Hello</p></div>
                    <div class="dot"> <div class="text_center_white">< 33 ></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to create a rectangle in the top and another in the bottom and add a circle in the bigger rectangle:

````
    <div style="position:absolute;height:50;width:100;top:0;left:0;background-color:blue">
    </div>
    
    <div style="position:absolute;height:50;width:50;top:200;left:0;background-color:yellow;border-radius:50%;">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;height:50;width:100;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:yellow">
    </div>
    
</section>```
````